# Trying to get multi sub-level JSON using Stripe API

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

I am trying to get multi-level variables from JSON with the Stripe API.  First level and second are fine, but then things get wonky.

From the docs:

```
Stripe\StripeObject JSON: {
  "id": "sub_D2SAhDWdvauEfI",
  "object": "subscription",
  "application_fee_percent": null,
  "billing": "charge_automatically",
  "billing_cycle_anchor": 1528851289,
  "cancel_at_period_end": false,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "created": 1528851289,
  "current_period_end": 1531443289,
  "current_period_start": 1528851289,
  "customer": "cus_D2S9eF9dXrGLVV",
  "days_until_due": null,
  "discount": null,
  "ended_at": null,
  "items": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "si_D2SAUS9fKsIVyB",
        "object": "subscription_item",
        "created": 1528851289,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "plan": {
          "id": "platinum-plus-711",
          "object": "plan",
          "active": true,
          "aggregate_usage": null,
          "amount": 999,
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1528848402,
          "currency": "usd",
          "interval": "month",
          "interval_count": 1,
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {
          },
          "name": "Platinum Plus",
          "nickname": null,
          "product": "prod_D2ROpdTqhux5Hz",
          "statement_descriptor": null,
          "tiers": null,
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_usage": null,
          "trial_period_days": null,
          "usage_type": "licensed"
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "subscription": "sub_D2SAhDWdvauEfI"
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_D2SAhDWdvauEfI"
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "plan": {
    "id": "platinum-plus-711",
    "object": "plan",
    "active": true,
    "aggregate_usage": null,
    "amount": 999,
    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
    "created": 1528848402,
    "currency": "usd",
    "interval": "month",
    "interval_count": 1,
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": "Platinum Plus",
    "nickname": null,
    "product": "prod_D2ROpdTqhux5Hz",
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "tiers": null,
    "tiers_mode": null,
    "transform_usage": null,
    "trial_period_days": null,
    "usage_type": "licensed"
  },
  "quantity": 1,
  "start": 1528851289,
  "status": "active",
  "tax_percent": null,
  "trial_end": null,
  "trial_start": null
}
```

Within that I am trying to get items->data->plan->active.  Here is my code.

On a side note, I see that after "data": [ there is that bracket there where there isn't a bracket elsewhere.  Why is that?

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/stripe/config.php");

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(self::get_private_stripe_key());

        $subdetails = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subid);


        $plan = $subdetails->items->data->plan->active;
```

Comment: `data` is an array (that's what the square-brackets mean) so you'll want `->data[0]->plan->...`

Comment: Phil, respectively that other answer may technically be a duplicate, but that answer isn't going to help someone using Stripe with the same problem and they won't find the answer with that other answer either in my humble opinion.  If they already KNOW the answer they might.